# For a MOS transistor, why is the maximum voltage of it be \$V_{dd}-V_{ov}\$?

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, maximum-ratings, common-source

Razavi stated that

> the maximum output swing at X or Y is equal to \$V_{DD}−(V_{GS}−V_{TH})\$

as shown in the following picture, the second picture is the Fig.4.3

[image: Razavi Chapter 4]
[image: Figure 9.4]
I don't understand why the equation for maximum output swing is written as..
$$ V_{DD}-(V_{GS}-V_{TH}) \tag{1} $$
?
For a common source amplifier with a resistor load at drain, the output voltage should be
$$V_{out}=V_{DD}-I_{DS}R_{D} \tag{2}$$
Due to equation 2, maximizing the output voltage swing entails maximizing the Drain-source current. I understand that the current maximizes when the drain-source voltage equals the overdrive voltage. If the above reasoning is correct, shouldn't the maximum output voltage be represent as
$$V_{out}=V_{DD}-\frac{1}{2}K_n{V_{ov}}^2R_{D} \tag{3}$$
instead of equation 1?

Reference: Razavi, Design of analog CMOS integrated circuits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you skipped the importance detail of chaptor 3, single-stage amplifier. let me recap for you.

First, look at this figure.  you see the single stage amplifier only behave close to linear if \$V_{out}\$ is between  \$V_{dd}\$ and  \$V_{gs}-V_{th}\$.

Note:The term \$V_{gs}-V_{th}\$ came form saturation region.

That why the maximum voltage range (with linear behavior) become.

$$ V_{DD}-(V_{GS}-V_{TH}) \tag{1} $$

Comment: I just figured it out , thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have just figured it out. 
First, my previous understanding is somehow swapped; I thought that Vdd is the minimum and \$V_{GS}-V_{TH}\$ is the maximum, which should be exactly the opposite. 
Secondly, for a CS stage like figure 4.3, the output voltage is exactly the Drain-Source voltage. The minimum requirement for the transistor to operate in the saturation region is when the Drain-Source voltage is equal to the overdrive voltage. That is to say:
$$V_{outmin}=V_{DS}=V_{OV}=V_{GS}-V_{TH}=V_{DD}-\frac{1}{2}K{V_{OV}}^2R_{d}$$
And since the maximum voltage is just the supply voltage \$V_{dd}\$,
we indeed have the maximum swing
$$V_{Omax}-V_{Omin}=V_{DD}-V_{OV}$$